# Vim match multiple ^M preceded by something on the line (ff=unix)

Tags: regex, vim, match

(^M here are ^V^M, ff=unix)

`s/^M*$/\^M/` works fine, convert 0-many ^M into one ^M on any line.

But trying to do this only on matching lines like "matchtext is here with more and more text^M^M^M" with `s/^matchtext.*\zs^M*$/\^M/` and it doesn't work, instead it adds one ^M ?

It's the behavior of `.*` here that i don't understand,
`s/\zs^M*$/\^M/` works but just introducing `s/.*\zs^M*$/\^M/` doesn't.

magic/nomagic issue? `s/.\\*\zs^M*$/\^M/` seems to work, but then again `s/matchtext.\\*\zs^M*$/^M/` doesn't.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What are you trying to accomplish? When I have `sometext.^M^M^M` and I do `:s/sometext.\zs^M*$/\^M/` then it replaces the three `^M`s with one `^M`. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: That turns out to be a special case, try changing the text to `sometext and more and more text^M^M^M` and `s/sometext.*\zs^M*$/\^M/` and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `.*` is matching everything including all of the trailing `^M`s which leaves nothing for your `^M*` to match, and it does match nothing because it's a `*` so matching 0 instances is allowed. The greediness of the first `*` dominates the greediness of the second `*`.

To fix it you could make the first `*` non-greedy (`:help non-greedy`) but I think you should just use the `:g` command, like this:

```
:g/^matchtext/s/^M*$/\^M/
```

Comment: Nice approach. Changing the `.` to `[^^M]` will also work: `s/^matchtext[^^M]*\zs^M*$/\^M/`, but I like your solution better.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the backslash which I forgot the first time. @Johnsyweb, the `[^^M]` approach has a slight difference: it'll stop at a `^M` in the middle of a line, which would be ignored by the others.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Alan, with your help i found the proper non-greedy form `s/^matchtext.\{-}\zs^M*$/\^M/` which works. Johnsyweb, that's a very logical solution, thank you for that.

Comment: I suppose this means I failed to get you interested in the `:g` command... too bad. It's versatile (can chain to other commands besides `s///`), portable (available in every vi version) and it's basically the command (inherited from ed) that gave "grep" its name

Comment: Yes it's versatile and i've been using it since ex days on a slow teletype, but in general i try to find out a suitable match (if just possible!) because that has wider uses and is easier to combine with other matches (in my opinion). Or maybe it's just a question of philosophy... ;) Sometimes it does matter that g is limited to single lines, whereas :s can be made to work across EOL's with \_. (sometimes important with natural language matching).

Comment: Something ate the backslash, i meant `\_.`